# Changing Jquery vertical tabs to menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, tabs

Referring from 
http://mehdi.biz/blog/2010/02/05/vertical-tabs-for-jquery-lovers/

i know it's very easy but i couldn't able to find a solution.. 
Just want to hide panel(content) when users move their mouse out from that icons.(Acting like a menu not like tabs don't want an active tab.)

How can i add that jquery code?

```
var $items3 = $('#vtab>ul>li');
$items3.mouseleave(function()
        {                           
        $('#vtab>div').hide();  
        }).mouseleave();
```

tried that code..it hides the tabs so i cant visit content of panel..

Ex: http://arkansas.gov/ 
panel at right side

Answer (score 0):

You are triggering the mouseleave right after you have attached it. Why? 
Instead of the javascript on vertical-tabs and yours use this: 
Add `display: none;` to `#vtab > div` in the css.

```
    var $items = $('#vtab>ul>li');
    var $contents = $('#vtab>div');
    $items.on('mouseenter', function() {
        $items.removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $contents.hide();
        var index = $items.index($(this));
        $contents.eq(index).show();
    });
    $('#vtab').on('mouseleave', function(){
        $items.removeClass('selected');
        $contents.hide();
    });
```

try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/suDyw/23/).
This will only display the tab content and select the tab on mouseenter and hide the content and de-select the tab on mouseleave.

Comment: have you checked the jsfiddle? it does. or what's wrong for you?

Comment: I've just tried IE, Chrome, FF. all works fine for me. What's going wrong for you?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/suDyw/8/ hovering that boxes,nothing happens..content statically exits there..nothing changes..

Comment: try this: http://jsfiddle.net/suDyw/14/ I haven't change it, but re-saved. when I hover over the tabs the content changes, red shows "Wellcome Home", green "Secure Login", blue "Online Support". I got the markup from the vertical-tabs-for-jquery-lovers page you refered.

Comment: thanks for your help rusci but that's not the case that i want... i can't hover over content home content,login content,etc.. it's disappering.. actually tabs should behave like a menu

Comment: I see. Try it now. I've edited the code. and updated the link. This should do what you want.

Comment: No problem. I've changed the code here too. Please mark as answered if you're happy with the solution.

Comment: i've tried but it says u need minimum 15 reputation to vote up..So i'll try to gain rep i'm so new..I'll mark as an answer as soon as possible..Thank you again!

Comment: my bad, I thought you can accept an answer without voting. no worries. ;)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/suDyw/23/ did u change the code ? it's not working anymore :/

Comment: the script you needed is here, I haven't changed anything else, just reused the css of vertical-tabs-for-jquery-lovers.as far as I know you cant change a certain jsfiddle. it creates a new one, so no I haven't changed it, and it is still working for me.